# How to convert the probability P/Q to P⋅Q−1 where Q is co-prime with mod

Tags: probability, probability-theory, prime-numbers

I was dealing with probability in programming but i was stuck on the final answer part.

Below is statement in which format i have to give the answer

Can you find the probabilities It can be proved that for each of these values, the probability can be expressed as a fraction PQ, where P and Q are integers (P≥0, Q>0) and Q is co-prime with 998,244,353. You should compute P⋅Q−1 modulo 998,244,353 for each of these values.

Below is probability that can be calculated on paper and 2nd line is for what i have to print can any1 explain how should calculate P.Q-1.

```
For 1st Input
Calculated Probability = 1/4 
Answer : 748683265
For 2nd Input
Calculated Probability was = 1/16 , 3/16 , 3/16 , 9/16
Answer that was given = 436731905 935854081 811073537 811073537
```

If anything is unclear then pls comment as iam new to community I am not very good at asking questions.
Thank you for your reply in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{p}{q} \equiv p \cdot q^{-1} \mod 998244353$$

Since $q$ is coprime with $998244353$, $q^{-1}$ always exist. It can be found using extended euclidean algorithm, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798654/modular-multiplicative-inverse-function-in-python).

For example, $\frac{1}{4} \equiv 4^{-1} \mod 998244353$.

You can check that $4 \cdot 748683265 = 2994733060 \equiv 1 \mod 998244353$,

so $4^{-1} \equiv 748683265 \mod 998244353$.

Comment: I should explain the extended euclidean algorithm a bit. Basically, you want to find $x$ such that $qx \equiv 1 \mod M \implies qx = Mk + 1 \implies qx-Mk = 1$ (Find $x, k$). It is guaranteed that a solution pair can be found when $q, M$ are coprime. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer? That would help greatly

Comment: Ohh i am new to stack exchange so didn't know about it srry about it.

Comment: No problem! :) Have fun here haha

Answer (score 0):

**Works when m and a are coprime**

The idea is to use [Extended Euclidean algorithms](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/euclidean-algorithms-basic-and-extended/) that takes two integers ‘a’ and ‘b’, finds their gcd and also find ‘x’ and ‘y’ such that

ax + by = gcd(a, b)

To find multiplicative inverse of ‘a’ under ‘m’, we put b = m in above formula. Since we know that a and m are relatively prime, we can put value of gcd as 1.

ax + my = 1 
If we take modulo m on both sides, we get

ax + my ≡ 1 (mod m)

We can remove the second term on left side as ‘my (mod m)’ would always be 0 for an integer y.

ax  ≡ 1 (mod m)

So the ‘x’ that we can find using Extended Euclid Algorithm is multiplicative inverse of ‘a’

Code:

[Modular multiplicative inverse Code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

p=998244353;
int power(int x, int y, int p) 
{ 
    int res = 1;      // Initialize result

```
x = x % p;  // Update x if it is more than or 
            // equal to p 

while (y > 0) 
{ 
    // If y is odd, multiply x with result 
    if (y & 1) 
        res = (res*x) % p; 

    // y must be even now 
    y = y>>1; // y = y/2 
    x = (x*x) % p; 
} 
return res;
```

}

// Returns n^(-1) mod p 
int modInverse(int n, int p) 
{ 
    return power(n, p-2, p); 
}

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved using [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). You can visit the following link for further info and code solutions:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplicative-inverse-under-modulo-m/

Also there is a [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61073745/9556205) on overflow for this.